# Eclipse Neon not detecting file updates/changes

Tags: java, eclipse

Im using Eclipse Neon and trying to create a swing application which reads an Excel file and write it to a JTextArea.

For the first run, the application is running successfully. However when i add few rows to the excel workbook. And then try to execute the application, it is throwing me ArrayOutOfBoundException while reading the just inserted line.

When i counted the no. of rows having data, it is displaying correctly but displaying the rows or storing it to another variable is throwing exception.

Please help me on how to make eclipse recogonize my file updates/ how to resolve this issue.

Note: I have already tried on changing the preference setting in window/preferences. But it did not help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you save the Excel file? Did you save it where the application is looking for it? If it's a resource in your application, what happens when you select it in an Eclipse explorer and choose *File>Refresh*?

Comment: Yes, i have saved the excel file. The path i mentioned for the application looking to it is valid. It is working fine if i have not made any amendments to excel. I have opened the excel file in the eclipse explorer and the changes are reflecting there. Also i tried the file>refresh. But still its throwing exception.